# listen to external change in db with typrorm

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

In my db is a table called Songs. 
I have a application that creates new songs in the db. 
I have a second application which acts as a api for the db which uses typeorm. 
I am wondering if it is possible to listen to changes in the db which are done by the first application.

Answer (score 0):

Through [Redis PubSub](https://cloudnweb.dev/2019/08/implementing-redis-pub-sub-in-node-js-application/), you can communicate between both applications.

Kafka is an option as well.

Or within NestJS it's possible through microservices.